# Sort on user defined properties

Tags: hugo, go-html-template

I'm using hugo v0.15
I'm trying to sort pages on custom property.

I define my subpages as following:

```
+++
title= "bla bla bla"
parent = "parent"
index = 0 # each page is assigned a unique index
+++
```

And in my parent template as following:

```
{{ range sort .Site.Pages ".Params.index" }}
    <a href="{{.RelPermalink}}">
          {{.Title}} {{.Params.index}}
    </a>
{{end}}
```

this doesn't fails at compilation, but the list is rendered empty.
what am i missing?

Comment: Just a heads up, `{{ range sort .Data.Pages ".Params.myparam" }}` worked for me on a section page. Maybe there was some other problem with your implementation?

Comment: @neRok 's solution worked for me too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, i was walking in the wrong direction.
I discovered that there's a default parameter is there just to be used for sorting, **"weight"**

So, the fix is:

```
use "weight" instead of "index"
```

and use weight

```
{{ range sort .Site.Pages ".Weight" }}
```

this fixed my issue, but there's still a problem using **user defined properties** for sorting.

Comment: `{{range .Site.Pages.ByWeight}}` is shorter.

Answer (score 4):

> but there's still a problem using user defined properties for sorting.

Create your custom, user defined parameter in the page front matter, such as "my-param" below:

```
+++
title = "The page title"
date = 2017-08-24T22:14:52-07:00
author = "Me"
banner = "img/default.jpg"
my-param = "100"
+++
```

In your template, add something like the following:

```
{{ range $paginator.Pages.ByParam "my-param" }}
```

Comment: what about reverse sorting for this ?

Comment: found it:  ` {{ range ($paginator.Pages.ByParam "my-param").Reverse }}`